# Assign two different emails for two different groups (but only one contact)?

Tags: civimail, email

Is it possible for one contact to subscribe to two different groups with two different emails – or will CiviCRM always send email to the primary email address?

IOW, is this possible?:

```
Robert Smith has two emails and is subscribed to two groups:
1. Group A sends to robert.smith@work.com
2. Group B sends to bob@home.com
```

Comment: Just found this which suggests assigning two different emails for two different groups (but only one contact) is not possible: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/add-non-primary-email-address-to-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a location type for each group - collect emails for that location using a profile.

Then when emailing click options (the spanner icon) for recipients to choose the location.

See answer + screenshot at [Add non-Primary email address to Group](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/add-non-primary-email-address-to-group) by Fabian